# cannot display fetched data in my javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have a json file and i fetched the data. However I cannot display it on the screen.
How can I display ? I get the data results in the console however I cannot reach the parametres like product name, price.

My code is below

```
index.html

<body>
    <div id="products"></div>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
index.js

fetch("./data.json")
.then(response => {
   return response.json();
})
.then(data => console.log(data));


showProducts = products => {
    const showProductsDiv = document.querySelector("#products");
    products.map(product => {
      const productElement = document.createElement("p");
      productElement.innerText = `product Name: ${product.name}`;
      showProductsDiv.append(productElement);
    });
  }
```

I also share console results

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you mean to say `.then(showProducts)` instead of sending it ONLY to the console?

Comment: @TimRoberts I did not quite understand the question but I fetched my json file and I can reach all the data in my console as in the pictures. However I want to display for example products' name , prices etc on browser. I want to show them in the div tag. How can I make this ? My code does not display

Comment: Did you not wrote this code?  It looks like the `showProducts` function is all set to create a `<div>` from the JSON results, but you aren't passing the JSON results to that function.  Instead, you're just dumping them to the console and you're done.  So, instead of dumping to the console, pass the results to that function .  That's what my comment said.

Comment: @TimRoberts so should I write .then(showProducts) instead of .then(data => console.log(data)); ? When I do this, data results disappear from the console. fetch is not working :/

Comment: OI course it disappears from the console, but it will appear in your `<div>`  Printing to the console is a debug technique.  Once you've seen it work, you don't need to see it any more.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your `showProducts` function.
Here is a sample code that will work for you too, but please, bear in mind, that I have used an example api. It's a bit different to yours that is why I have `results` array and `name.first`.

```
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10';

fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(data => {
  return showProducts(data)
})

showProducts = products => {
  const showProductsDiv = document.querySelector("#products");
  products.results.map(product => {
  const productElement = document.createElement("p");
  productElement.innerText = `product Name: ${product.name.first}`;
  showProductsDiv.append(productElement);
 });
}
```